# what's the point of this code in cocos2d-x?

Tags: cocos2d-x

```
void CCRenderTexture::begin()
{
    ..
    director->setProjection(director->getProjection());
    ...
```

I can't figure out what it's doing here.

Does anyone know why does it do this?

Comment: where did you find this code? Or you've written it.

Comment: @dg_no_9,the newest code has changed the name to `RenderTexture::begin`, but the logic is still the same.

Answer (score 2):

This code chunk looks unnecessary but believe me its not. The reason is that this `setProjection` method not just updates the projection variable it is affiliated with but it also sets up an OpenGL projection according to the provided projection.

Comment: sorry, I need a more insight answer.